# How to remove the double quotes from array value which generates dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have a simple concept here.I am getting some values on click of first button in my console,which comes as increment index++. I have already combined the value and put into an array onclick of second button, now the output is coming as

> ["$('#chart1')", "$('#chart2')", "$('#chart3')"],

But the only thing I need to fix is to remove the double cotes that surrounds each value inside array.I need the output like this

> [ $('#chart1'), $('#chart2'),$('#chart3')]

Here is code below.

### html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button id="button1" class="button1">submit1</button> </div>
<div><button id="garray" class="button1">genarete-array</button> </div>
```

### script

```
 var index = 0;
    var id = [];

    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        index++;
        id.push(`$(\'#chart${index}\')`)
        console.log('chart' + index);
    });

$('#garray').on('click', function() {
console.log(id);
//output [ $('#chart1'), $('#chart2'),$('#chart3')]
})
```

Comment: you can not do that. because when you push to array it will become string

Comment: You can try to add numbers/promises/objects:
var arr = [];
arr.push(3);
console.log(arr[0] === '3'); // false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not store it without the double quotes but you are able to replace it just like below.

```js
  var index = 0;
var id = [];

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    index++;
    var temp="$('#chart"+index+"')";
    id.push(temp);
    console.log('chart' + index);
});

$('#garray').on('click', function() {

var string = JSON.stringify(id);
console.log(string.replace (/"/g,''));

//output [ $('#chart1'), $('#chart2'),$('#chart3')]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button id="button1" class="button1">submit1</button> </div>
<div><button id="garray" class="button1">genarete-array</button> </div>
```

One more thing is that if you wish to remove quotes from other than string type you may use map function.

```
stringvaribale.map(parseFloat), stringvaribale.map(Number),etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
id.push($(`#chart${index}`));
```

You can test it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/x25btyn1/5/

Answer (score 0):

Once you push it to an array it normally is string according to your data, so for that situation maybe you should convert it to `JSON.stringify` then try to use a regular expression `data.replace(/"/g,"")` to get rid of the cotes